# Getting undefined on button click (textbox value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass value to the edit form on Edit button click (Anchor tag). When i'm alerting it it gives me **undified** in `alert`.
When i'm alerting Charector value it shows proper result, but not for ID's.

**here is my code:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_edit" data-statusCode="'+data[i].statusCode+'" data-status="'+data[i].status+'">Edit</a>
```

data[i].status in alert gives me Status value, but data[i].statusCode gives Undified. As in Image I'm getting values in response.

[image]

**My Edit code:**

```
//get data for update record
    $('#showList').on('click','.item_edit',function(){
        var statusId = $(this).data('statusCode');
        var status = $(this).data('status');

        $('#Modal_Edit').modal('show');
        alert(statusId);
        $('[name="statusId_edit"]').val(statusId);
        $('[name="status_edit"]').val(status);

    });
```

Any kind of help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to get text() of that .item_edit instead of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with camel case in your `data-statusCode` attribute.

Change `data-statusCode="'+data[i].statusCode+'"`

to `data-status-code="'+data[i].statusCode+'"`

Comment: Thanks, its working. Will you please explain difference between data-status-code and data-statusCode as my value stored in statusCode and not in status-code.

Comment: `data-status-code` is only for the html. You can keep the JS value in `data.statusCode` but `.data()` function expects `-` separated values and converts them to camel case automatically.